# Most efficient MySQL solution for querying against coordinates

Tags: mysql, geolocation, query-optimization, spatial-query

I have a database of geolocalized objects:

- id
- latitude
- longitude

I am querying the database to fetch objects that are inside a box:

```
WHERE longitude >= - 33.83789
  AND longitude <= 33.837891
  AND latitude >= 4.214943
  AND latitude <= 40.979898
```

There is one index on: `latitude, longitude`.

**Is there a more efficient way of storing/querying the database?** Right now, depending of the box coordinates/objects density, query times vary from 0.1s to more than 1s.

I know about [MySQL Spacial extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html), but it seems a bit of work to use and I have no idea if it will be easier/more efficient.

*Additional info*: I am also planning of performing simple distance-based queries (fetch objects near a specified location) in the future.

Comment: nothing about efficiency, for readability use [between and](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: @nawfal I agree it would at least look better, I didn't bother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient way of storing/querying the database?

Absolulely, yes! [Spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html) are exactly designed to solve this problem.

> I know about MySQL Spacial extension, but it seems a bit of work to use and I have no idea if it will be easier/more efficient.

It's not easier (but it's not *much* harder), and it *is* more efficient. For large data sets it can be a *lot* more efficient.

Comment: Oh I wasn't expecting it would be that much of an improvement for the performances, great! Just one question, is the `SPATIAL` index type a part of the MySQL Spatial extension? Or is the Spatial extension something different? Because the `SPATIAL` index seems interesting in my case, but I don't want to miss out (again) on the MySQL spatial extension.

Comment: @Matthieu: The `SPATIAL` index is the magic that makes it faster. You will also need to change your query to use the one of the [spatial functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html).

Comment: Would you be able to provide some example how should the DB administrator introduce and use those indexes?